Rigorous Proofs on Stationarity and Reduction of Spurious Correlations in Time Series
I understand that stationarity in time series analysis is crucial, especially for inference, as it helps reduce the risk of spurious regressions. In non-stationary series, correlations are more likely to appear significant due to changing variance or mean, leading to misleading inferences about causation.
Is there a rigorous proof or theoretical explanation that supports this? Specifically, why does non-constant variance over time increase the likelihood of spurious correlations? How does stationarity enhance the reliability of correlation implying causation? Any mathematical insights or references would be helpful!
